# XSL embed original XML file

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am transforming XML files with XSL to HTML files. Is it possible to embed the original XML file in the HTML output? When yes, how is that possible?

**Update 1:** To make my need better understandable: In my HTML file, I want a form where I can download the original XML file. Therefore I have to embed the original XML file into my HTML file (e.g. as a hidden input field)

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*embed the original XML file in the HTML output*". Please post a (small) example of the XML input and the expected HTML output.

Comment: I just edited my question: I want a form in my HTML file, where I can download the original XML file. Therefore I have to embed the XML file in the HTML file (e.g. as an hidden input field).

Comment: If someone wants to download the file the usual way is to provide a link to the file. If you want to put something into a form then it rather sounds as if you want to upload the data in the form. You haven't really explained whether you want to perform the XSLT 1.0 transformation inside or outside of the browser and whether the XML file itself or the resulting HTML is loaded by the browser and whether that happens from the file system or from a HTTP(S) server.

Comment: I can not add a download link to the file, because the file is part of a secured system. Therefore I've to embed it into the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the nodes through you can simply do `<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>` where you want to insert them, however, putting arbitrary XML nodes into HTML does not make sense usually. If you want to serialize an XML document to plain text to render it then you can use solutions like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/, for instance:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <section>
              <h1>Test</h1>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
              <section>
                  <h2>Source</h2>
                  <pre>
                      <xsl:apply-templates mode="xml-to-string"/>
                  </pre>
              </section>
          </section>      
        </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

transforms an XML input like

```
<data>
    <item att="value">
        <!-- comment -->
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </item>
</data>
```

into the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section>
         <h1>Test</h1>
         <ul>

            <li>

                       bar

            </li>

         </ul>
         <section>
            <h2>Source</h2><pre>&lt;data&gt;
    &lt;item att="value"&gt;
        &lt;!-- comment --&gt;
        &lt;foo&gt;bar&lt;/foo&gt;
    &lt;/item&gt;
&lt;/data&gt;</pre></section>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```